# Node Red Bluemix Application

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, node-red

Is there any way to provide front end to the NODE-RED App in BLUEMIX? I mean if there is a way to attach Angular.JS or PHP to the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed a Node-RED app into an application based on AngularJS. Node-RED is based on Node.js and there is even official documentation on how to embed it. Take a look here: http://nodered.org/docs/embedding

You need to add the node-red package to the requirements and configure some settings. All is explained in the sample code provided in the above document.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to use angularJs in combination with node-red is the template node from the dashboard ui:

npm package dashboard ui: 
https://github.com/node-red/node-red-dashboard

detailed description of usage: 
http://noderedguide.com/tag/template-node/